# how convolution neural network maps pooling layer to convolution layer in terms of connection

Tags: deep-learning

I am unable to post image because reputation.Yo can look at image at this url.  http://fastml.com/images/cifar/lenet5.png
In architecture of CNN 
How (after layer 2 - Pooling layer) 6@14x14 feature maps to 16@10x10  feature? Can you tell what is the size of convolution kernel and ho 
w many of them need to use to connect 6@14x14 feature maps to 16@10x10 feature map.

Answer (score 0):

C3 uses 5x5 kernel, overlapping. (14 - (5-1) = 10). You can find more info in [original LeCun et al 1998 paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98.pdf) that describes LeNet-5 in detail.